# Why does domainObject.discard() not work in @Transactional service in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails, transactions

I have a method in my service, with `@Transactional` annotation.
Inside, I'm doing various stuff with 2 objects, and at the end, I want to `.discard()` changes on one of them, so it's not saved in this transaction.
What I do is send information about object2 to my ActiveMQ queue, where it's picked up by a listener, there's some work done there and in the end it saved in another transaction.
Object1 is supposed to save as usual.

This however, does not work. What happens is, that listener on my queue is able to `.get()` the object, perform some changes on it and `.save()` it, before the first transaction is over. Thanks to that, I get `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)`.

I perform `.get()` of the objects inside the service. Transaction is saved when exiting service and coming back to the controller.

What do I have to do to prevent Grails from saving object2 in the main transaction?

Comment: Can you not put the object2 access in a separate method in your service and have it not be part or your outer transaction?

Comment: No. That's one of the points of using queuing mechanism - to do it in a separate transaction [it's not the only point, mind you].

Comment: I don't know the answer to this off the top of my head, but a workaround for now could be to .read() the object you might not want to save instead, then it won't be persisted unless you explicitly save it.

Comment: Is there an answer to this question already?

Comment: @Gideon sorry, but I've asked this 4 years ago. It's been long time since I dropped Grails and to be honest I don't even remember which project I needed it for.

Comment: @Krystian Well, thank you either way. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `.refresh()` on object2 before the end of your service method.  This will reload and overwrite any data in object2 with the updated data in your database, so the optimistic locking `version` variable matches (which I think is what is causing your `Exception`).  And Hibernate won't need to flush the object as it now matches the database.

Comment: this may work but it will generate additional query and i don't want that.  Besides it seems it's not object2 alone which needs refreshing but it's collections as well.